# Add column to state whether two purchases were made by same customer within 30 days

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I can reduce to two columns - CustomerID and SaleDate. I have already ensured that this dataset includes only customers with at least two sales. I would like to add a 3rd column that states whether or not the second sale (or 3rd sale compared to the second etc.) was within 30 days of the previous sale.

| CustomerID | SaleDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 14/09/2021 |
| 1 | 30/09/2021 |
| 1 | 03/10/2021 |
| 2 | 23/07/2021 |
| 2 | 24/07/2021 |

With the new column entitled 'SaleDate' adding a '1' if the resale is within 30 days of the previous sale and a '0' if not (e.g. it's the first sale or not within 30 of the previous sale). So the end result, in this case, would be:

| CustomerID | SaleDate | ResaleWithin30 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14/09/2021 | 0 |
| 1 | 30/09/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 03/10/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 23/07/2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 24/07/2021 | 1 |

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to check whether the next record is within 30 days of the present record.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID) %>% 
  mutate(SaleDate = as.Date(SaleDate, tryFormats = "%d/%m/%Y"),
         ResaleWithin30 = as.integer(SaleDate - lag(SaleDate) <= 30),
         ResaleWithin30 = replace_na(ResaleWithin30, 0))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   CustomerID [2]
  CustomerID SaleDate   ResaleWithin30
       <int> <date>              <int>
1          1 2021-09-14              0
2          1 2021-09-30              1
3          1 2021-10-03              1
4          2 2021-07-23              0
5          2 2021-07-24              1
```